# Rename files in a directory the simplest way in a script

Tags: unix, rename

I want to write a script that add '0' at the end of the files that doesn't have it.

This is what I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1
do
    echo $file

    ls $file | grep "\0$"

    if ["$?"="1"] 
    then

    fi

done
```

I don't know hot to target the files in a way I can rename them

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *[!0]; do mv "$file" "${file}0"; done
```

For each name that does not end `0`, rename it so it does.  Note that this handles names with spaces etc in them.

---

> I want to give the script a directory, and it will rename the files in it that do not end in 0.  How can I use this in a way I can tell the script which directory to work with?

So, make the trivial necessary changes, working with a single directory (and not rejecting the command line if more than one directory is specified; just quietly ignoring the extras):

```
for file in "${1:?}"/*[!0]; do mv "$file" "${file}0"; done
```

The `"${1:?}"` notation ensures that `$1` is set and is not empty, generating an error message if it isn't.  You could alternatively write `"${1:-.}"` instead; that would work on the current directory instead of a remote directory. The glob then generates the list of file names in that directory that do not end with a `0` and renames them so that they do.  If you have Bash, you can use `shopt -s nullglob` you won't run into problems if there are no files without the `0` suffix in the directory.

You can generalize to handle any number of arguments (all supposed to be directories, defaulting to the current directory if no directory is specified):

```
for dir in "${@:-.}"
do
    for file in "$dir"/*[!0]; do mv "$file" "${file}0"; done
done
```

Or (forcing directories):

```
for dir in "${@:-.}"
do
    (cd "$dir" && for file in *[!0]; do mv "$file" "${file}0"; done)
done
```

This has the merit of reporting which arguments are not directories, or are inaccessible directories.

There are endless variations of this sort that could be made; some of them might even be useful.

---

> Now, I want to do the same but, instead of the file ending with '`0`', the script should rename files that do not end with '`.0`' so that they do end with '`.0`'?

This is slightly trickier because of the revised ending.  Simply using `[!.][!0]` is insufficient.  For example, if the list of files includes `30`, `x.0`, `x0`, `z.9`, and `z1`, then `echo *[!.][!0]` only lists `z1` (omitting `30`, `x0` and `z.9` which do not end with `.0`).

I'd probably use something like this instead:

```
for dir in "${@:-.}"
do
    (
    cd "$dir" &&
    for file in *
    do
        case "$file" in
        (*.0) : skip it;;
        (*)   mv "$file" "${file}0";;
        esac
    done
    )
done
```

The other alternative lists more glob patterns:

```
for dir in "${@:-.}"
do
    (cd "$dir" && for file in *[!.][!0] *.[!0] *[!.]0; do mv "$file" "${file}0"; done)
done
```

Note that this rapidly gets a lot trickier if you want to look for files not ending `.00` — there would be a 7 glob expressions (but the `case` variant would work equally straight-forwardly), and `shopt -s nullglob` becomes increasingly important (or you need `[ -f "$file" ] && mv "$file" "${file}.0"` instead of the simpler move command).

Comment: How can I use this in a way I can tell the script which directory to work?

Comment: It works. Now, I want to do the same but, instead of '0' with '.0'. The script is not recognizing a file named 30. I'm guessing it is because "." works as some kind of wildcard, replacing '3' ?

Comment: So, you want to rename files that do not end with `.0` so that they do end with `.0`?  That's fiddlier because the recognition pattern is fiddlier.  Please confirm I've interpreted your requirement correctly (a response comment).

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.